# SWT.CLOSE, SWT.MAX, SWT.MIN without SWT.TITLE?

Tags: java, shell, window, swt

I am essentially trying to reproduce something like this in Java SWT but have been unsuccessful so far:

[image]

The problem that I am seeing is that as far as I can tell `SWT.TITLE` is required to display `SWT.CLOSE`, `SWT.MAX` and `SWT.MIN`

Can anybody tell me if there is a nice way of doing this, either by styling a single shell or by using multiple shells and accessing the close, min, max components?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this answer I assume targeting Windows is enough. If you want portability, stop reading now.

Unfortunately, the moment you remove the WS_CAPTION GWL_STYLE, the buttons are also lost. I cannot say for sure, but I don't think this can be done just messing around with window styles. Maybe if you use AERO you can, but that limits the operating systems that can run the code.

If you insist to have this, I can offer you only the next best thing: put your own buttons, but make them look as close to the native caption buttons as possible.

This is how it looks with theme:

[image]

And this is how it looks like with classic theme:

[image]

There is still work to align buttons, change state when it is hot/pressed or maximized/restored, but it is a starting point.

I know this is not exactly what you asked, but maybe it helps.

And here is the code that creates the windows:

```
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Point;
import org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS;
import org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.RECT;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.*;

public class CaptionItemSnippet {

    private static final char[] WINDOW_CLASS = className("WINDOW");
    private static final int WP_MINBUTTON = 15;
    private static final int WP_MAXBUTTON = 17;
    private static final int WP_CLOSEBUTTON = 18;

    private static final int DFC_CAPTION = 1;

    private static final int DFCS_CAPTIONCLOSE = 0x0000;
    private static final int DFCS_CAPTIONMIN = 0x0001;
    private static final int DFCS_CAPTIONMAX = 0x0002;
    private static final int DFCS_CAPTIONRESTORE = 0x0003;
    private static final int DFCS_CAPTIONHELP = 0x0004;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Display display = new Display();
        final Shell shell = new Shell(display);

        int gwlStyle = OS.GetWindowLong(shell.handle, OS.GWL_STYLE);
        //remove title bar
        gwlStyle &= ~OS.WS_CAPTION;
        // add maximize button: does not work
        gwlStyle |= OS.WS_SYSMENU | OS.WS_MAXIMIZEBOX;
        OS.SetWindowLong(shell.handle, OS.GWL_STYLE, gwlStyle & ~OS.WS_CAPTION);

        final Button minimizeButton = createButton(shell, WP_MINBUTTON, DFCS_CAPTIONMIN);
        minimizeButton.setBounds(125, 0, 20, 20);
        final Button maxButton = createButton(shell, WP_MAXBUTTON, DFCS_CAPTIONMAX);
        maxButton.setBounds(145, 0, 20, 20);
        final Button closeButton = createButton(shell, WP_CLOSEBUTTON, DFCS_CAPTIONCLOSE);
        closeButton.setBounds(165, 0, 20, 20);

        shell.setSize(200, 200);
        shell.open();
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
                display.sleep();
            }
        }
        display.dispose();
    }

    private static Button createButton(final Composite parent, final int partId, final int uState) {
        final Button button = new Button(parent, SWT.PUSH);
        button.addListener(SWT.Paint, new Listener() {
            @Override
            public void handleEvent(Event e) {
                final Point size = button.getSize();
                final RECT rect = new RECT();
                rect.left = 0;
                rect.right = size.x;
                rect.top = 0;
                rect.bottom = size.y;

                if (OS.IsAppThemed()) {
                    final int theme = OS.OpenThemeData(parent.handle, WINDOW_CLASS);
                    OS.DrawThemeBackground(theme, e.gc.handle, partId, OS.TS_NORMAL, rect, null);
                    OS.CloseThemeData(theme);
                } else {
                    OS.DrawFrameControl(e.gc.handle, rect, DFC_CAPTION, uState);
                }
            }
        });
        return button;
    }

    private static char[] className(String s) {
        final char[] chars = new char[s.length() + 1];
        System.arraycopy(s.toCharArray(), 0, chars, 0, s.length());
        chars[chars.length - 1] = 0;
        return chars;
    }
}
```